# Play Framework How to update a the session within a request

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm following the documentation of the play framework and action composition.  My action checks the current session to see if a user is present if so a UserRequest is returned and if not I would like to create a guest user, store them in the session of the request and return a UserRequest with the updated session.

```
class UserRequest[A](val email: String, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

class UserAction @Inject()(val parser: BodyParsers.Default, dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends ActionBuilder[UserRequest, AnyContent] with ActionTransformer[Request, UserRequest] {

  val userRepo = new UserRepository(dbConfigProvider)(executionContext)

  def transform[A](request: Request[A]) = {
    request.session.get("user") match {
      case None        => createGuestUser(SecureRandomUtil.generateSecureRandom(24)).map { u => 
        new UserRequest(u.email, request.withSession("user"->u.email))
      }
      case Some(email) => Future.successful(new UserRequest(email,  request))
    }
  }
```

However withSession is not a defined method on the request object.  Is there a way to modify the session on the request object?

Answer (score 0):

First, session field of `Request` object is not just field, it's lazy field that calculated from user's cookies.

So use can update request to make it have another session but you will not update user cookies that way and next request will create you a new anonymous user. So you probably want to update `Result` of the Action adding `withSession` there or install permanent cookie (so it'll not be removed when user closed his browser tab).

Otherwise, I'm not sure why you want to update session with user email if you already have in your `UserRequest`.

On your question - your code is very similar to one in play docs about [Scala action composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaActionsComposition). And on the same page, it shows how to create a new request with some fields altered.

In you case, it will be something like

```
new WrappedRequest[A](request) {
  override val session = request.session + ("user" -> u.email)
}
```

Comment: I ended up not needing the functionality and used a cookie instead.  I did use a filter that checks the cookie on every request then creates it if it does not exist.  I also believe I tried the method above and it did not work.  The session would not change.  For the sake of closing this question I'll give it a shot later on.

Comment: As I wrote it will create new Session object that you can pass further. But as big part of my answer says it'll not change actual user session. So I found what you wanted to do very strange and probably wrong, but nevertheless, it solves your actual question.